# How can I call this jOOQ generated function taking a custom bound type?

Tags: jooq, postgresql-9.6

I originally had the following SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION resolve_device(query JSONB) RETURNS JSONB...
```

and the following code calling the method generated by jOOQ:

```
final JsonArray jsonArray = jooqDWH.select(resolveDevice(queryJson)).fetchOne().value1().getAsJsonArray();
final JsonObject o = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
```

This worked fine.  I needed to return a real device object rather than a JSON blob though, so I changed the SQL function to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION resolve_device(query JSONB) RETURNS SETOF device...
```

and the code to:

```
final ResolveDeviceRecord deviceRecord = jooqDWH.fetchOne(resolveDevice(queryJson));
```

but I am getting a runtime error:

```
org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type class com.google.gson.JsonElement is not supported in dialect DEFAULT
```

Many other parts of my code continue to work fine with the custom binding I have converting JsonElement to JSONB, but something about the change to this function's signature caused it to stop working.

I tried a few different variants of DSL.field() and DSL.val() to try to force it to be recognized but have not had any luck so far.

Comment: Using a custom binding is the way forward here. Can you post your code generation configuration that worked before your change and no longer works now? Meanwhile, I'll post a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a bug in jOOQ or a misconfiguration in your code generator. I'll update my answer once it is clear what went wrong.

#### Workaround:

Meanwhile, here's a workaround using [plain SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/):

```java
// Manually create a data type from your custom JSONB binding first:
final DataType<JsonObject> jsonb = SQLDataType.OTHER.asConvertedDataType(jsonBinding);

// Then, create an explicit bind variable using that data type:
final ResolveDeviceRecord deviceRecord = 
    jooqDWH.fetchOptional(table("resolve_device({0})", val(queryJson, jsonb)))
           .map(r -> r.into(ResolveDeviceRecord.class))
           .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the workaround.  My generator config is huge, but I will happily see if I can narrow down two alternative function declarations that show the difference.

Comment: @deinspanjer: No worries. Just ping me when you have an update in the question...